# How to combine icomma and otherlanguage?

Tags: math-mode, punctuation, incompatibility, icomma

How to enjoy `otherlanguage` while still keeping the behavior of `icomma`?

This code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{icomma}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}

\begin{document}
$0,123$

\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
\end{otherlanguage}

$0,123$
\end{document}
```

produces:

[image: MWE]

(I really hate my life right now.)

Comment: Do you need `icomma` in the first place? With `\DecimalMathComma` in the preamble, `babel-french` does the same as `icomma`, I believe.

Comment: I got another problem with `\DecimalMathComma` under LuaLaTeX. It is the topic of another question I will post on TeX.SE ;)

Comment: I think it is a different problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can limit the changes of the active characters due to  `otherlanguage`  environment, enclosing it between `{}`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{icomma}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\begin{document}
$0,123$
{\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
 It's a Wonderful Life
\end{otherlanguage}}
$0,123$
\end{document}
```

If you use this environment a lot, you can simplify your life with a macro:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\newcommand\Eng[1]{{\begin{otherlanguage}{english}#1\end{otherlanguage}}}
\usepackage{icomma}
\begin{document}
$0,123$
\Eng{It's a Wonderful Life}
$0,123$
\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't really solve the issue, because `icomma` would be inactive in the English part.

Comment: @egreg And is not that right and desirable? It would be quite peculiar have commas as decimal marks also in the English part. Then  1,000 should be read as one or as one thousand? The question is not very clear at this respect, but I understood that the problem  is only the French part after the English part.

Answer (score 3):

The 'reset' code after the change of language deliberately alters a setting. To undo that, we can use `\extrasfrench`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{icomma}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\addto\extrasfrench{\mathcode`\,="8000 }
\addto\noextrasfrench{\mathcode`\,="8000 }
\begin{document}

$0,123$
\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
\end{otherlanguage}
$0,123$
\end{document}
```

(The package `icomma` works by making `,` 'math active', so we need to leave that turned on.)

### Update

With the release of `babel-french` version v3.2f (2017/01/15), the issue seems solved.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage{icomma}

\begin{document}

$0,123$

\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
$0,123$
\end{otherlanguage}

$0,123$

\end{document}
```

[image]